# i am trying to get the no.of matches of response code 200 in the response assertion

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

The code i have written for that is as folows:

```
try {
    byte []
    samplerdata = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();
    String
    samplerdatastring = new String(samplerdata, "UFT-8");
    vars.put("samplerdata", samplerdatastring);
    vars.get(samplerdata);
    int
    matches = StringUtils.countMatches(samplerdata, "200");
    vars.put("matchescount", String.valueOf(matches));
    vars.get(matchescount);
} catch (Throwable
ex
)
{
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

It results in an rror as follows:

> jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``try {     byte [] samplerdata = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();    Stri . . . '' : TargetError

Can any one please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format the code in your question. As it is now, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

try as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

try {
    String
    samplerdata = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();
    vars.put("samplerdata", samplerdata);
    vars.get("samplerdata");
    int
    matches = StringUtils.countMatches(samplerdata, "200");
    vars.put("matchescount", String.valueOf(matches));
    log.info(vars.get("matchescount"));
} catch (Throwable
ex
)
{
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

---

Solved issues in the code:

1. `getResponseCode` returns String, so store it in `String` but not in `byte[]`
2. Removed additional code used for conversion from `byte[]` to `String`
3. Added import statement for `StringUtils`
4. while retrieving `matchescount`, we should keep it in double quotes in `vars.get`. similarly for `samplerdata`

---

Instead of ctx, you can use prev, which returns SampleResult object.

existing:

```
String
    samplerdata = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();
```

you can also try:

```
String
    samplerdata = prev.getResponseCode();
```